# Javascript DOM object diagram

Tags: javascript, dom, diagram

I have been searching for a good DOM object diagram to be used by javascript.
I know that a search for `javascript DOM object diagram` gives a lot of them, like this one that seems very clear:

[image]

Any of you have one that shows a more complete relationship between DOM and javascript?

Comment: Relationship between DOM and JavaScript?  Do you mean something that says parentNode of x,y,z?

Comment: @austincheney That is! Something that shows in one diagram the DOM and ways to refer their elements via javascript (ECMAscript).

Comment: +1 I am searching for same thing. Full list of what JS can access.

Comment: But every page has its own unique DOM structure. The [MDN Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is a good place to find information on the properties of different node types. The somewhat ancient [element tree](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tree/htmltree.htm) at the old "Blooberry" site is also sort-of interesting, though dated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a very small portion of a DOM tree:

```
<html>
 |
 +-- <head>
 |     |
 |     +...
 |
 +-- #text
 |
 +-- <body>
       |
       +...
```

Even if you leave only properties (no methods) and only those properties that point to `Node`s (no attributes, styles, no text or number properties), exclude HTML-specific APIs (such as those on your diagram) and omit some properties, you'll still get a complicated diagram (excuse my poor graphviz skills):

[image]

(here boxes are objects, labeled after their most derived DOM interface name, edges are labeled after properties).

It might be interesting to produce several "cheat sheets" for different categories of DOM APIs, but you could elaborate more on why and in what situations would the diagram you're talking about be useful.

Myself, I find the [developer.mozilla.org's DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference), the relevant specifications, and http://docs.jquery.com for jQuery enough.

---

P.S. the source for the graphviz diagram in case someone needs it:

```
digraph {   //rankdir=LR;
//  size="30,10";
node [shape="rect"];
Window -> Document [label="document"];
Document -> Window [label="defaultView"];
Document -> "Element (<html>)" [label="documentElement"];
"Element (<html>)" -> Document [label="ownerDocument"];

html [label="Element (<html>)"];
head [label="Element (<head>)"];
textBetweenHeadBody [label="Text"];
body [label="Element (<body>)"];

html -> head [label="firstChild,\nchildNodes[0]\nchildren[0]"];
head -> html [label="parentNode" color=grey fontcolor=grey];
html -> textBetweenHeadBody [label="childNodes[1]"];
html -> body [label="lastChild\nchildNodes[2]\nchildren[1]"];
body -> html [label="parentNode" color=grey fontcolor=grey];

head -> textBetweenHeadBody [label="nextSibling"];
textBetweenHeadBody -> head [label="previousSibling"];
textBetweenHeadBody -> body [label="nextSibling"];
body -> textBetweenHeadBody [label="previousSibling"];

head -> body [label="nextElementSibling\npreviousElementSibling" fontcolor="blue" color="blue" dir=both];
//body -> head [label=""];


{rank=same; head textBetweenHeadBody body}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In native JavaScript you are limited to the XML DOM properties:

- parentNode
- nextSibling
- previousSibling
- firstChild
- lastChild
- nodeName
- nodeValue
- childNodes
- attributes

Since the properties are few and limited there is not really any need for a diagram.  If you need a high degree of specificity and control in relative node access you may wish to look at XPath.

Comment: This is not really true at all if one is talking about the DOM of the HTML document (and, given the diagram in the question, that appears to be the case).

Comment: There are far more properties on `Element`

Comment: There are other properties that are not a part of the DOM specification, such as scrollHeight and clientHeight and so forth.  The properties listed are those available from the standard DOM.

Comment: @austincheney [`Node`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#node) has more. i.e. `ownerDocument`, `textContent`, `nodeType`, etc. [`Element`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#element) also has a whole bunch more.

Comment: @Raynos possibly, but the question is about the DOM and not about defacto properties outside the DOM.

Comment: @austincheney The DOM is defined in the standard, go read the standard. What your talking about is probably "the set of properties implemented on an Element in most implementations of the DOM". Implementations of the DOM have nothing to with the DOM though.

Comment: The DOM is its own standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html  Specifically look there at the section Interface Node, Attributes

Comment: +1 I agree with you that a diagram mentioning these properties it should be desirable.

Comment: @austincheney your referencing DOM 1 core instead of DOM4. please reference the latest standard.

Comment: DOM level 4 is not a standard.  The latest standard is DOM level 3, which is an extension to DOM level 2 and not an update thereof.

Comment: @austincheney do you say this because DOM4 is a draft rather then completed work? Couldn't you say the same for HTML5, HTML5 is not a standard. Or what about WHATWG HTML the living document, it's a living document, therefore never finished, therefore not a standard?

Comment: I have always said that about HTML5.  WHATWG HTML is not recognized as a official standard of HTML.

Comment: @austincheney "not recognised". By whom? WHATWG is the browser vendors for all I know, and I think only the browsers vendors _care about_ and _recognise_ the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know about the interfaces exposed by the DOM then read the [DOM Specification](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html)

A brief outline is that `document` is an instance of [`Document`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-document) and you basically go from there.

Comment: It would be great have a resume in a diagram. If not complete at least a `Full list of what JS can access` as anubhav-saini says.

Comment: @NomikOS I may draw such a full list. This is a vastly non trivial time consuming task.

Comment: +1 Yes, as you comment in austincheney's answer seems that, so forget `Full list...`. As you see this question seems be shared by other users too. I think that a diagram is needed where we can see how js interact with the DOM. That is the question. Properties like `parentNode` and `nextSibling` should be mentioned. Thanks!